# Subclass collection view: execution was interrupted, reason: Attempted to dereference an invalid ObjC Object

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview, unrecognized-selector

I just implemented a collection view within a collection view cell as property

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "EMSubCollectionView.h"

@interface EMYearCell : UICollectionViewCell

-(void)setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate:(id<UICollectionViewDataSource>)dataSourceDelegate index:(NSInteger)index currentSection:(NSInteger)section;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet EMSubCollectionView *collectionView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *monthHeader;

@end
```

The method in my implementation looks like this:

```
-(void)setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate:(id<UICollectionViewDataSource>)dataSourceDelegate index:(NSInteger)index currentSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    self.collectionView.dataSource = dataSourceDelegate;
    self.collectionView.tag = index;
    self.collectionView.numberOfCurrentSection = section;
    [self.collectionView reloadData];
}
```

I just wanted to give my collection view a second "tag-property", so I subclassed the corresponding collectionview property:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface EMSubCollectionView : UICollectionView

@property NSInteger numberOfCurrentSection;

@end
```

When I run my app, it immediately crashes:

[image: crash]

What is wrong with my code? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution was pretty simple: I just forgot to assign the new class to the corresponding collection view in my storyboard. Now everything works like a charm.